# How to make TravisCI run flow/test/lint in parallel?

Tags: travis-ci

In my `.travis.yml` I have this.

```
script:
- yarn lint    
- yarn flow  
- yarn test --runInBand
```

I was wondering is there a way to get them to run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's few suggestions in Travis docs you could use, i.e. split your build into multiple jobs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/speeding-up-the-build/

Another thing you could do is to employ GNU parallel:

```
addons:
    apt_packages:
        - parallel

script:
    - parallel --gnu --keep-order ::: 'yarn lint' 'yarn flow' 'yarn test --runInBand'
```

The GNU parallel command has lots of options you might want to tweak to your needs. Read more about the tool on their website https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 2):

To split Travis into several jobs you can either use stages or add the option **env**

This would run each script sequentially:

```
script: 
  - yarn lint
  - yarn flow
  - yarn test --runInBand
  - yarn build
  - yarn cypress
```

To get them to run in parallel jobs. You can update it to the code below (Though keep in mind this is limited by the number of concurrent jobs available. https://travis-ci.com/plans)

> Using **Build Stages**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '9'

install:
  - travis_retry yarn install 

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      name: "Flow/Lint/Test"
      script:
        - yarn lint
        - yarn flow
        - yarn test
    -
      name: "Cypress"
      script:
        - yarn cypress
```

> Using **env**

```
env:
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn lint"
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn flow"
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn test --runInBand"
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn build"
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn cypress"

script: $TEST_SUITE
```

Another option would be to just have two concurrent builds.

```
env:
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn lint && yarn flow && yarn test --runInBand && yarn build"
  - TEST_SUITE="yarn cypress"

script: $TEST_SUITE
```

This might or might not improve the overall build times. For me majority of my build time was in cypress while lint + flow + test took a few minutes. So by separating cypress to be in its own job, I sped up my overall build time by a few minutes.